# Facebook API, Querying the "stream" table returns "null" for the "type" field

Tags: facebook-fql

Running this [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2Cactor_id%2Ctarget_id%2Ctype%2Cpermalink%2Ctype%2Cmessage%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D104266592953439%20AND%20is_hidden%3D0%20LIMIT%200%2C50) in the API explorer :

```
    SELECT post_id,actor_id,target_id,type,permalink,type,message FROM stream WHERE source_id=104266592953439 AND is_hidden=0 LIMIT 0,50
```

returns null for every "type" field. Why is correct "type" field not showing up ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried that query and also got type as null, but when i changed the WHERE to "WHERE source_id=me()" , I say the correct type for each post.

I'm not entirely sure, but it might have something to do with the source_id you are specifying. Maybe since it is a page and not an actual user, the type won't be returned.

Once again I'm not positive, but it might be something you can look deeper into.